# duplicating rows by quantity

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to duplicate the rows by the quantity identified in the columns. i am having problems with this one

so far i have been able to duplicate the rows by quantity but haven't been able to add which 'Block' that row is for

this is the data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp2Qx.png)

expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnpyK.png)

this is the code i am using. it's an adjusted version of another code

Sub CopyBlocks()
    Dim StartRow, LastRow, NewSheetRow As Long
    Dim n, i As Integer

```
Worksheets("test").Activate
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).Row
NewSheetRow = 10

For StartRow = 10 To LastRow
n = CInt(Worksheets("test").Range("AA" & StartRow).Value)
For i = 1 To n
    Worksheets("test2").Range("C" & NewSheetRow).Value = Worksheets("test").Range("g" & StartRow).Value
    Worksheets("test2").Range("D" & NewSheetRow).Value = Worksheets("test").Range("H" & StartRow).Value
    Worksheets("test2").Range("E" & NewSheetRow).Value = Worksheets("test").Range("I" & StartRow).Value
    Worksheets("test2").Range("F" & NewSheetRow).Value = Worksheets("test").Range("J" & StartRow).Value
    Worksheets("test2").Range("G" & NewSheetRow).Value = Worksheets("test").Range("K" & StartRow).Value

    NewSheetRow = NewSheetRow + 1
Next i
Next StartRow
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55580205/edit) to provide the code you have so far?

Comment: would you ever have a number greater than 1 in your crosstab?

Comment: In SQL this would be an UNPIVOT. Use that as your VB search reference

Comment: 1st search. https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/ Apaprently you can do this in just a GUI without VBA

Comment: @RyanB. yes the numbers could be any value. but most likely under 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using excel 2016, then you can use PowerQuery to unpivot this data set very nicely.  Keith has a very useful link for you in the comments.  Filter away the zeros and you're almost at your solution.  A little complexity comes into the game with the possibility of those duplicate rows.  The List.Numbers function can get you there if you're interested in getting into the guts of the M language just a little bit.

However, it's also not too hard to crack this out in VBA.  I'd suggest a little different strategy which is just to iterate over the range of your crosstab, plucking out the row and column headers when you hit a count more than 0.

```
Sub foo()

    Dim outputRow As Integer

    'start your output at whatever row is best
    outputRow = 1

    'set your range to cover the counts in your crosstab
    For Each c In Range("A1:Z99")
        If c.Value > 0 Then

            For i = 1 To c.Value

                    'write the values off the current row headers over to comparable positions in your output row
                    Worksheets("test2").Cells(outputRow, 3).Value = Cells(c.Row, 1).Value
                    Worksheets("test2").Cells(outputRow, 4).Value = Cells(c.Row, 2).Value
                    .
                    .
                    .

                    'write the values off the current column headers into output row
                    Worksheets("test2").Cells(outputRow, 8).Value = Cells(1, c.Column).Value

                outputRow = outputRow + 1
            Next i

        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Good luck, hope it helps

Comment: If you go with the power query unpivot, here's a post about repeating the rows for the number of times you have in your counts.  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/power-bi/977045-pq-repeat-rows-n-times.html

Comment: thank you. i don't have Power Query but tried using the code you provided, just not sure what you set Dim 'c' As

Comment: You shouldn't need to dimension c, but if you're being by the book you can Dim c as Range